# Why is my puppet agent failing to get a certificate from the puppet server?

Tags: puppet

When I run the following command from the puppet agent: puppetssl bootstrap I get the following output:

```
Info: csr_attributes file loading from /home/mkhan244/.puppetlabs/etc/puppet/csr_attributes.yaml
Info: Creating a new SSL certificate request for puppet-client1.mkhan244.ops
Info: Certificate Request fingerprint (SHA256): A6:6B:DE:23:C4:28:22:6A:E1:55:A6:C1:5E:AF:9C:31:21:5F:FC:B8:0D:6A:AA:7E:40:4D:F8:3F:5B:59:96:1F
Info: Certificate for puppet-client1.mkhan244.ops has not been signed yet
Couldn't fetch certificate from CA server; you might still need to sign this agent's certificate (puppet-client1.mkhan244.ops).
Info: Will try again in 120 seconds.
```

[puppet ssl bootsrap output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mZv8W.png)

When I try to run the following command from the puppet server: puppetserver ssl sign --all it gives me the following output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    8: from /opt/puppetlabs/server/apps/puppetserver/cli/apps/ca:5:in `<main>'
    7: from /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_gems/gems/puppetserver-ca-2.4.0/lib/puppetserver/ca/cli.rb:100:in `run'
    6: from /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_gems/gems/puppetserver-ca-2.4.0/lib/puppetserver/ca/action/sign.rb:68:in `run'
    5: from /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_gems/gems/puppetserver-ca-2.4.0/lib/puppetserver/ca/action/sign.rb:68:in `new'
    4: from /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_gems/gems/puppetserver-ca-2.4.0/lib/puppetserver/ca/certificate_authority.rb:26:in `initialize'
    3: from /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_gems/gems/puppetserver-ca-2.4.0/lib/puppetserver/ca/certificate_authority.rb:26:in `new'
    2: from /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_gems/gems/puppetserver-ca-2.4.0/lib/puppetserver/ca/utils/http_client.rb:25:in `initialize'
    1: from /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_gems/gems/puppetserver-ca-2.4.0/lib/puppetserver/ca/utils/http_client.rb:156:in `make_store'
/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_gems/gems/puppetserver-ca-2.4.0/lib/puppetserver/ca/utils/http_client.rb:156:in `add_file': system lib (OpenSSL::X509::StoreError)
```

[puppet ssl ca sign output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xnSc2.png)

I was trying to connect the puppet agent to the server and have the server sign the certificate but I'm getting an error.

Comment: It's hard to be sure from the information provided, but my guess would be that you are trying to run the `puppetserver` command as a user who does not have sufficient privilege to do the needed work.  In a standard installation, most subcommands of `puppetserver` need to be run as root.

Comment: Note also that you normally need to run the agent as root, too, for similar reasons, and you do not appear to be doing that.  On the agent side, moreover, various Puppet configuration and data are user-specific, so the agent doesn't necessarily fail directly because of being run as non-root. Under most circumstances, however, it won't do what you want, either.

Comment: Will try it out and see if it works out.